# How to redirect jsp/servlets from apache server to tomcat via tomcat conector mod_jk

Tags: php, apache, jsp, servlets

Well Friends,
I am a kind of newbie, so it might sound a basic or relatively easy question. All I am trying to do is: I developed a small application using JSP and Servlets  deployed it on one of the machines in the network using tomcat5.5.35. It worked perfectly and I could see JSP/Servlets running as expected. 
Now I thought of developing the remaining pages in PHP and integrate PHP and JSP/Servlets togther using Apache and tomcat connecters.

Apache Version - 2.2.22 win 32 x86 no ssl. Tomcat Connecter - tomcat-connectors-1.2.36-windows-i386-httpd-2.2.x

```
I called a php script from PHP Directory and it got displayed as expected.
```

**Problem Statement:** Apache is not forwarding JSP and Servlets to tomcat.

Copied mod_jk.so to /modules

I created **worker.properties** and copied it under \conf directory with following contents

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
worker.worker1.lbfactor=50
worker.worker1.cachesize=10
worker.worker1.cache_timeout=600
worker.worker1.socket_keepalive=1
worker.worker1.socket_timeout=300
```

**Modified httpd.conf as**

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
ServerName localhost:80
<ifmodule mod_jk.c>
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
 JkLogLevel DEBUG
</ifmodule>

LoadModule    jk_module  "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_jk.so"
JkWorkersFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/workers.properties"
JkShmFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/mod_jk.shm"
JkLogFile "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/mod_jk.log"
JkLogLevel    debug
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/apache-tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/automationutil"
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.php no-jk
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.cgi no-jk
JkMount  /* worker1
JkMount  /*.jsp worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

**server.xml for tomcat**

tomcat logs dont show any errors while I could see the below in mod_jk.logs

```
1:06:16 2012] [5580:3828] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/pages/loginrelated.html' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:3828] [debug] jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3723): no match for /automationutil/pages/loginrelated.html found
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:3828] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/pages/loginrelated.html' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:3828] [debug] jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3798): no match for /automationutil/pages/loginrelated.html found
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:3828] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/pages/loginfooter.html' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:3828] [debug] jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3723): no match for /automationutil/pages/loginfooter.html found
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:3828] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/pages/loginfooter.html' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:3828] [debug] jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3798): no match for /automationutil/pages/loginfooter.html found
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/pages/index_settings.jpg' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3723): no match for /automationutil/pages/index_settings.jpg found
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/pages/index_settings.jpg' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:16 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3798): no match for /automationutil/pages/index_settings.jpg found
[Wed May 16 21:06:23 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/pages/helppage.jsp' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:23 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3723): no match for /automationutil/pages/helppage.jsp found
[Wed May 16 21:06:23 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/pages/helppage.jsp' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:23 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3798): no match for /automationutil/pages/helppage.jsp found
[Wed May 16 21:06:32 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/LoginApp' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:32 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3723): no match for /automationutil/LoginApp found
[Wed May 16 21:06:32 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1131): Attempting to map URI '/automationutil/LoginApp' from 0 maps
[Wed May 16 21:06:32 2012] [5580:4996] [debug] jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3798): no match for /automationutil/LoginApp found
```

I have mapping for servlets in web.xml and they work fine in tomcat. But not sure why apache is not handling them correctly:(. Do we need mapping for JSP as well?

Would be very thankful and appreciate any help that could get me going. Have searched net for last few days but no gain.

Comment: If you obtained correct answer I'll be expected... thank you.